# PromptChoice changing options after receiving user input

Tags: c#, botframework

I have overridden the PromptDialog.PromptChoice for an abstract type. I have two different children that I want to share the same logic for, but I need to guarantee that certain variables are available for part of my TryParse logic. For one of the children, I don't have any issues here. However, for the other child, I am running into really bizarre behavior. When I call from my dialog CustomPromptChoice.Choice(context, function, options), I see options to be what I am expecting. The user is presented with the correct list of options, but after selecting an option, in the TryParse logic, I see that all of the options have changed. Obviously, my TryParse will always fail. Has anybody else ever seen this behavior?

Here is the base class:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ExtractionClass
{
    public List<ExtractionClass> children;
    public ExtractionClass parent;
    public string name;
    public string value;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public ExtractionClass() { }
    public ExtractionClass(string name, string value, ExtractionClass parent)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    //upon initialization, guarantee that children is filled correctly
    public abstract void SetChildren();
    //use to check if child is a where match
    public abstract bool IsWhereMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query="");
    //use to check if child is a when match
    public abstract bool IsWhenMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query="");
    //use to check if child is a who match
    public abstract bool IsWhoMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query="");
    //use to check if child is a what match
    public abstract bool IsWhatMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query="");
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of the child class that doesn't work:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChildClass1:ExtractionClass
{
    public Dictionary<ChildClass1, int> childrenLookup;
    public Dictionary<string, ChildClass1> childrenNames;
    private dynamic content;
    public string spokenName;
    static HashSet<string> childrenToKeep = new HashSet<string>()
    static List<string> ignoreNames = new List<string> ();
    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> nodeNameSynonyms = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public static HashSet<string> WhoNodes = new HashSet<string>();
    public ChildClass1(dynamic content)
    {
        this.children = new List<ExtractionClass>();
        this.childrenLookup = new Dictionary<ChildClass1, int>();
        this.childrenNames = new Dictionary<string, ChildClass1>();
        this.parent = null;
        this.name = String.Empty;
        this.value = String.Empty;
        this.spokenName = String.Empty;
        this.content = content;
    }
    public ChildClass1(string name, string value, List<string> synonyms) : this(null)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.spokenName = name;
        double doubleValue;
        int integerValue;
        bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(value, out integerValue);
        if (isInt)
        {
            this.value = string.Format("{0}", integerValue);
        }
        else {
            bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(value, out doubleValue);
            if (isDouble)
            {
                this.value = string.Format("{0:N2}", doubleValue);
            }
            else
            {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public override void SetChildren()
    {
        //pretty long and complicated
    }

    public override bool IsWhereMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query = "")
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool IsWhenMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query = "")
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool IsWhoMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query = "")
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool IsWhatMatch(ExtractionClass child, string query = "")
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is a stripped down version of the class that does work:

```
public class ChildClass2: ExtractionClass
{
    public Address address;
    public Rating rating;
    public string description, telephone, spokenName;


    public ChildClass2(string name, string value, ExtractionClass parent) : base(name, value, parent) { children = new List<ExtractionClass>(); }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }


    public override void SetChildren()
    {
        //a bit of a mess but works as expected
    }


}
```

What makes no sense to me though, is that I make this call in my Dialog:

```
ExtractionPromptChoice.Choice(context, this.CarouselEntityHandler, nodeOptions);
```

And then when I step through the stack, I see it return to the user the right options. nodeOptions in the last instance of my control is set correctly, but when I go to the ExtractionPromptChoice TryParse logic, the options are different. nodeOptions ends up holding a list of ChildClass1 types, but the promptchoice is defined for the ExtractionClass.

Edit: It turns out that something about my code is causing the remote server to return a 400 Bad Request error in my MessagesController code.

Comment: No two children are alike. When a behavioral issue comes up, it's best to have all the facts otherwise one might feign favoritism, which of course will upset the other sibling, then they'll fight, scream, balk and date each others high-school sweethearts which leads to more fights... can you paste some code so we can help you?

Comment: haha good point. I didn't paste any code because I couldn't even begin to figure out where to look. I'll add the children code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have bad logic elsewhere in my code that catches errors without propagating them. I was getting a 400 Bad Request response because in ChildClass1 I have a dynamic, which breaks the serialization. This error isn't thrown anywhere, and I'm not sure exactly why I was seeing the wrong PromptOption choices, but I don't think the behavior is well defined when I catch and don't rethrow an error.